# intersection of 2 paths

Tags: approximation, data-analysis

Could somebody please advise me on the best approach to take to find the intersection points of 2 paths. Each path is a data set of distance against time (I want to avoid curve fitting) and each path may intersect the other more than once-are there existing methods/theorems for this?

Many thanks for any guidance,

Stephen.

Comment: Are these paths in two dimensions or more? Would finding the intersections of the line segments between sampled points suffice? About how many data points are expected on average and at the maximum? (This determines the kind of algorithm.) Do you need all intersections or just some of them?

Comment: Is an intersection a point where the two paths agree in time as well as position?  Or simply positions that the two paths both reach, possibly at different times?